# What is dojo.store.Memory?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, dojo

I'm trying to learn about dojo's MVC patterns, but the documentation is vague.

About **dojo.store.Memory** it says:

*An in-memory object store that queries, modifies, and accesses client-side in-memory data.*

And about **dojo.store**:

*Dojo Store is an uniform interface for the access and manipulation of stored data.*

When do you use **Memory**? "Client-side in-memory data" sounds to me like normal javascript functionality.

Comment: So `dojo.store` is the API and `.Memory` is one implementation of that API (in memory). Do you know what an interface is?

Comment: I just don't really get what Memory offers that isn't already in the core dojo.store.

Comment: It's just an implementation of the store, that's the whole point. The idea is that you want to store data, although *where* you store it changes from project to project, and more importantly, can change within a single project. So if you write your code to store in memory with `dojo.store.Memory` and then decide you want to change the store, not to be in memory, but to be in HTML5 storage, or remote storage, you (more or less) only change one line of code. That's the idea of an interface - a layer of abstraction that removes the implementation specifics, so changes like this can be smooth.

Comment: The two are not different, they are parent and child. They are not competing; when you say you're using `dojo.store.Memory` you're using the methods defined by `dojo.store`. The interface is one and the same.

Comment: For a wider understanding of abstraction I suggest reading up a little about object oriented design. The idea of an interface (among other similar concepts like abstract classes, inheritance, data privacy/visibility) is standard in the OOP world, and more accessible in that context than in your day-to-day javascript world.

Comment: I get it, Davin, Thanks. If you put this in an answer, we can wrap the question up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So `dojo.store` is the API and `.Memory` is one implementation of that API (in memory).

It's just an implementation of the store, that's the whole point. The idea is that you want to store data, although where you store it changes from project to project, and more importantly, can change within a single project. So if you write your code to store in memory with `dojo.store.Memory` and then decide you want to change the store, not to be in memory, but to be in HTML5 storage, or remote storage, you (more or less) only change one line of code.

That's the idea of an interface - a layer of abstraction that removes the implementation specifics, so changes like this can be smooth.

The two are not different, they are parent and child. They are not competing; when you say you're using `dojo.store.Memory` you're using the methods defined by `dojo.store`. The interface is one and the same.